# onBackpressed() Going to same activity for first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onbackpressed

I try using finish() also but end ups like same problem, Every time it goes to same activity for the first time. If i use intent to go back means resulted activity gets reloading, So for that case i need only onBackPressed() function.

```
 mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if(type.equals(AppConstantsUtils.VIDEO)) {

      onBackPressed();

    }
    else{
      onBackPressed();

    }
```

This is I'm using in before Tabfragment

```
 private void setupUi(View view) {
mMediaVp = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.media_view_pager);
mMediaVp.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.media_tab_layout);
mTabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>(3);
if(pos.equals("1")) {
  fragments.add(new PhotoListFragment());
}
else if(pos.equals("2")) {
  fragments.add(new VideoListFragment());
}
else if(pos.equals("3")) {
  fragments.add(new AudioListFragment());
}
else{
  fragments.add(new VideoListFragment());
}

ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>(3);
if(pos.equals("1")) {
  titles.add("Photos");
}
  else if(pos.equals("2")) {

  titles.add("Videos");
}
  else if(pos.equals("3")) {
    titles.add("Audios");
  }
  else {
    titles.add("Videos");
  }
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), titles, fragments);
mMediaVp.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mMediaVp);
}
```

Comment: Your if-else statement do the same action for both cases...

Comment: I've used Intent for vid type befor, Thats the reason I didn't removed it yet.

Comment: Are you using  onBackPressed() on Fragment ?

Comment: no, I'm using it in Activity to go back to fragment @AGMTazim

Comment: Post your code for onBackPressed();

Comment: @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    //moveTaskToBack(true);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You are since using fragements you should read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) .
You just can't use `onBackPressed()` you have to add the fragments to backstack when you navigate to the fragment and popbackup when you call `onBackPressed()`. Hope that help